# How does one integrate $E^2(r)$ on $r$ to conclude that the relative power contained within $w_0$ is $1 - 1/e^2 = 0.86$ of the total beam power?

Tags: electric-fields, laser, laser-cavity

In a chapter on the basics of laser physics, my textbook says the following:

> The $c/2L$ spacing of resonance is typical of the so-called longitudinal modes, or $\text{TEM}_{00}$ modes, characterised by an electric field distribution given by:
> $$E(r) = E_0 \exp -r^2/w_0^2 \tag{A1.3}$$
> In the Gaussian field distribution given by Eq.A1.3, the parameter $w_0$ has the meaning of a characteristic radius, called the *spot size* of the laser beam.
> In particular, $w_0$ is the radius at which the field amplitude drops off to $1/e = 0.37$ and the power density (proportional to $E^2$) drops off to $1/e^2 = 0.13$ of the maximum value. In addition, by integrating $E^2(r)$ on $r$, we find that the relative power contained within $w_0$ is $1 - 1/e^2 = 0.86$ of the total beam power.

I'm confused by this part:

> ... by integrating $E^2(r)$ on $r$, we find that the relative power contained within $w_0$ is $1 - 1/e^2 = 0.86$ of the total beam power.

How does one integrate $E^2(r)$ on $r$ to conclude that the relative power contained within $w_0$ is $1 - 1/e^2 = 0.86$ of the total beam power? Mathematically, it seems that integrating this would just result in another expression, not a specific value, like $0.86$. I get the impression that I'm missing something here, so I'd appreciate it if someone would demonstrate what is meant.

Comment: “contained within $w_0$“ places limits on the integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $E(r) = E_0 e^{-r^2/w_0^2}$, then
$$\int |E|^2 \mathrm dA = \int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm d\phi \int_0^{w_0} r\ \mathrm dr  \big(E_0^2 e^{-2r^2/w_0^2}\big)$$

Comparing this to the total power in the beam (the same integral, but taking the upper integration bound on $r$ to $\infty$) gives you the fraction in question.

Comment: Ahh, yes, it is explained in detail here: http://www.yorku.ca/marko/PHYS2212/Lab10.pdf